# efficiently saving and loading game state with NSUserDefaults

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsuserdefaults

I've been using NSUserDefaults to save my game score but I want to take it to another level of storing all the game state (coins, scores, enemies created, distance covered and more). How can I save and load all these multiple parameters of the game efficiently using NSUserDefaults?

Comment: first you make dictionary of you game state and then you store it into NSUserDefaults and retrieve that from same.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "efficiently"?